# How to deal with major companies flat-out ignoring your contact attempts about serious bugs on their website as well as refunds?

Tags: online, food, sweden

I'm forced to order groceries home these days. This is in Sweden

The company I order from has a bug which keeps silently switching the delivery address from whatever you entered and saved, to the one associated with the payment card you use for the payment, every single time you make an order. This has caused them to deliver the groceries to the completely wrong address (with me as the only person who suffered from it) before I started double-checking it every single time and manually changing the information back.

When I report this, they simply ignore it. No response whatsoever. The bug is never fixed.

And when they failed to deliver a watermelon (the delivery person accidentally broke it on the way, and claimed it would be refunded), nothing has happened with that for many months, in spite of countless e-mails by me. No silent refund. No apology. No response whatsoever.

I sent the e-mails to all e-mail addresses I could find on their website. In fact, after a while, I got tired of manually sending the e-mails and set up a script to e-mail them every hour (originally, it was only every 8th hour), since allegedly they get such a flood of e-mails all the time that mine get lost.

Is there any legal recourse for failing to fix issues like these?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127462/discussion-on-question-by-slatton-how-to-deal-with-major-companies-flat-out-igno).

Answer (score 4):

### What would be the most reasonable thing to do?

Live with it.

Oh, and stop breaking the law with your automated emails. Illegality on their part does not justify illegality on your part. Also, it’s likely that this activity has caused your email address to be blocked automatically which may explain why they aren’t contacting you.

From a legal point of view, that’s the only reasonable option. You do have valid grounds for a lawsuit for the value of the watermelon but the cost of filing will be a couple of orders of magnitude greater than the value of the melon so doing so isn’t “reasonable”.

If you want to vent, the internet offers a wide variety of social media platforms for which that seems to be their primary focus. But that’s got nothing to do with the law.

Answer (score 2):

#### Refund

Just lodge a card chargeback claim with your bank for the value of the melon, attach the order confirmation/receipt, describe what happened. Not only you will get your money back but it will also educate them to answer emails: chargebacks are painful to merchants.

#### Bugs

They don't owe you a pleasant user experience ordering stuff on their website. You have to watch carefully for the right address to be submitted before committing to an order. But if, for example, the delivery address gets switched to the wrong one when accepting your order despite you submitting the right one and they are ignoring your attempts to correct it, you will likely have a case for a small claims court / dispute tribunal (whatever exists for this in Sweden).

Answer (score 2):

Lets tackle the actual issues at hand here and ignore the rant:

**"Can I force a company to resolve an issue with their website which causes me minor inconvenience?"**

No.  Unless the issue falls under disability law and the described issue does not sound like it ever would - they are defaulting your delivery address to your payment address, this isn't an accessibility issue.

**"How can I recover a promised refund which never materialised?  The actual value is low."**

Every EU country, including Sweden, is required to have a small claims process, and Sweden has just that - https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/dealing-with-customers/solving-disputes/european-small-claims-procedure/index_en.htm

So long as your promised refund is lower than 5,000 Euros, you can ask a court to adjudicate on your claim.